# How to remove column and cells in a gridview before export to excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I using ASP.NET Gridview and am exporting to excel with button click. I need to remove a column and cell before exporting to excel. Oddly enough it seems to work on one grid when I use `RemoveAt`, but not this one. I'm not sure what's going on, because I think this should be rather simple to do. The excel sheet still shows the column and cell that I removed.

I've tried setting `gridPCO.Columns[0].Visible = false`, but no go.

```
 protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ProposedCourseOfferings.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);



        gridPCO.RenderControl(htw);
        gridPCO.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        gridPCO.Rows[gridPCO.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.RemoveAt(0);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

I would like remove said column and cell from the gridview before exporting excel.

Comment: It seems to remove columns before render the Gridview content in HtmlTextWrite.

Comment: Don't render a GridView to an HTML file like you're doing. That's just gross. It's not a real Excel file. Grab the underlying data that you're binding the GridView, then use a library like EPPlus, ClosedXML, or Open Office SDK to generate a real Excel.